# Is this Anti-Scraping technique viable with Robots.txt Crawl-Delay?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, robots.txt

I want to prevent web scrapers from *agressively scraping* 1,000,000 pages on my website. I'd like to do this by returning a "503 Service Unavailable" HTTP error code to bots that access an abnormal number of pages per minute. I'm *not* having trouble with form-spammers, just with scrapers.

I don't want search engine spiders to ever receive the error. My inclination is to set a robots.txt crawl-delay which will ensure spiders access a number of pages per minute under my 503 threshold.

Is this an acceptable solution? Do all major search engines support the crawl-delay directive? Could it negatively affect SEO? Are there any other solutions or recommendations?

Comment: Why not change divs and tags from time to time.Will save you from much scrappers as they will crash ...?

Comment: @confusedMind I could do this but it requires additional work every month. I was hoping that just blocking them or slowing them down would be enough of a deterrant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have built a few scrapers, and the part that takes the longest time is allways trying to figure out the site layout what to scrape and not. What I can tell you is that changing divs and internal layout will be devastating for all scrapers. Like ConfusedMind already pointed out.

So here's a little text for you:

**Rate limiting**
To rate limit an IP means that you only allow the IP a certain amount of searches in a fixed timeframe before blocking it. This may seem sure way prevent the worst offenders but in reality it's not. The problem is that a large proportion of your users are likely to come through proxy servers or large corporate gateways which they often share with thousands of other users. If you rate limit a proxy's IP that limit will easily trigger when different users from the proxy uses your site. Benevolent bots may also run at higher rates than normal, triggering your limits.

One solution is of course to use white list but the problem with that is that you continually need to manually compile and maintain these lists since IP-addresses change over time. Needless to say the data scrapers will only lower their rates or distribute the searches over more IP:s once they realise that you are rate limiting certain addresses.

In order for rate limiting to be effective and not prohibitive for big users of the site we usually recommend to investigate everyone exceeding the rate limit before blocking them.

**Captcha tests**
Captcha tests are a common way of trying to block scraping at web sites. The idea is to have a picture displaying some text and numbers on that a machine can't read but humans can (see picture). This method has two obvious drawbacks. Firstly the captcha tests may be annoying for the users if they have to fill out more than one. Secondly, web scrapers can easily manually do the test and then let their script run. Apart from this a couple of big users of captcha tests have had their implementations compromised.
Obfuscating source code

Some solutions try to obfuscate the http source code to make it harder for machines to read it. The problem here with this method is that if a web browser can understand the obfuscated code, so can any other program. Obfuscating source code may also interfere with how search engines see and treat your website. If you decide to implement this you should do it with great care.

**Blacklists**
Blacklists consisting of IP:s known to scrape the site is not really a method in itself since you still need to detect a scraper first in order to blacklist him. Even so it is still a blunt weapon since IP:s tend to change over time. In the end you will end up blocking legitimate users with this method. If you still decide to implement black lists you should have a procedure to review them on at least a monthly basis.

Comment: It seems there is not perfect solution for this problem. It's a terrible shame, but something we must deal with as developers none-the-less. Thanks for your input Carl.