# Scrapy : preventive measures before running the scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm about to scrape some 50.000 records of a real estate website (with Scrapy).
The programming has been done and tested, and the database properly designed.

But I want to be prepared for unexpected events.
So how do I go about actually running the scrape flawlessly and with minimal risk of failure and loss of time?

More specifically :

- Should I carry it out in phases (scraping in smaller batches) ?
- What and how should I log ?
- Which other points of attention should I take into account before launching ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, study the following topics to have a general idea on how to be a good web-scraping citizen:

- [Web scraping etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette)
- [Screen scraping etiquette](http://ask.metafilter.com/95415/Screen-scraping-etiquette)

---

In general, first, you need to make sure you are legally allowed to scrape this particular web-site and follow their *Terms of Use* rules. Also, check web-site's `robots.txt` and respect the rules listed there (for example, there can be [`Crawl-delay`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Crawl-delay_directive) directive set). Also, a good idea would be to contact web-site owner's and let them know what you are going to do or ask for the permission.

Identify yourself by explicitly specifying a `User-Agent` header.

See also:

- [Is this Anti-Scraping technique viable with Robots.txt Crawl-Delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945698/is-this-anti-scraping-technique-viable-with-robots-txt-crawl-delay)
- [What will happen if I don't follow robots.txt while crawling?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180108/what-will-happen-if-i-dont-follow-robots-txt-while-crawling)

---

> Should I carry it out in phases (scraping in smaller batches) ?

This is what [`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) setting is about:

> The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before
>   downloading consecutive pages from the same website. This can be used
>   to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.

[`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain) and [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-ip) are also relevant.

Tweak these settings for not hitting the web-site servers too often.

> What and how should I log ?

The information that Scrapy puts on the console is pretty much extensive, but you may want to log all the errors and exceptions being raised while crawling. I personally like the idea of listening for `spider_error` signal to be fired, see:

- [how to process all kinds of exception in a scrapy project, in errback and callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069128/how-to-process-all-kinds-of-exception-in-a-scrapy-project-in-errback-and-callba)

> Which other points of attention should I take into account before
>   launching ?
>   You still have several things to think about.

At some point, you may get banned. There is always a reason for this, the most obvious would be that you would still crawl them too hard and they don't like it. There are certain techniques/tricks to avoid getting banned, like rotating IP addresses, using proxies, web-scraping in the cloud etc, see:

- [Avoiding getting banned](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned)

Another thing to worry about might be the crawling speed and scaling; at this point you may want to think about distributing your crawling process. This is there `scrapyd` would help, see:

- [Distributed crawls](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls)

Still, make sure you are not crossing the line and staying on the legal side.

Comment: +1 summarized what I was trying to write. =) Other settings that may be useful are ``CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_{DOMAIN,IP}`` and there is also the [Autothrottle extension](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html).

Comment: @elias thank you, added a note about `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_{DOMAIN,IP}` settings. Thanks for the point about `autothrottle`.

Comment: Answer comprehensive on the ethical side. Still having some practical doubts though. For example : how do I minimize negative effects from a software/hardware problem during the scrape, or an internet connection loss ?

Comment: And as to the batches, I wasn't exactly referring to DOWNLOAD_DELAY. I was asking myself if there's any advantage to first scraping the 10.000 first records, then the next 10.000 (in a different run) and so on....

Comment: @SLeon as for the internet connection loss, `Scrapy` has [`RetryMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry) built-in - by default, it would retry 2 times if the page wasn't downloaded. As for batches, I'm not really sure what the benefits of splitting the records into separate consecutive runs could be.